# joining two arrays with a row separater in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two arrays -

```
        selectedGuids = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                             return $(this).attr('Guid');
                        })
                        .get();
        selectedUserNames = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                             return $(this).attr('userNames'); 
                        })
                        .get();
```

so I got selectedGuids and selectedUserNames arrays.

Now I want to merge each column as comma separated and each row as semicolon separated.

For eg.

```
  - selectedGuids : Array[3]
     0: "1698E748-01F9-413B-9B84-E2BC4DD5AE53"
     1: "EFD318D5-FF83-41E8-A213-CD934E23AAEA"
     2: "C6382CA2-0EC7-41DC-A8B1-A3F234CB4EB9"
  - selectedUserNames : Array[3]
     0: "abc"
     1: "xyz"
     2: "pqr"
```

the result should be like this -

```
var resultshouldbelikethis = "1698E748-01F9-413B-9B84-E2BC4DD5AE53, abc;EFD318D5-FF83-41E8-A213-CD934E23AAEA,xyz,C6382CA2-0EC7-41DC-A8B1-A3F234CB4EB9,pqr"
```

Please note there should be semicolon between each row.

Comment: Why tagged with C# and .Net?

Comment: Start with not having 2 separate arrays.

Comment: @Jamiec, example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, having 2 arrays just makes this a pain to do. You can use `map` to make an array of objects with 2 properies which will look like

```
{ guid: 'xxxxxxxx', userName: 'xyz' }
```

Do this like:

```
var items = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                         return {
                            guid: $(this).attr('Guid'),
                            userName: $(this).attr('userNames')
                         };
                    }).get();
```

Then the last bit is easy, you just need to `reduce`

```
 var result = items.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
    return previousValue + currentValue.guid + ',' + currentValue.userName + ';';
 });
```

Another way to do this is to form the strings for each item inside the `map` and then just use `join`:

```
var items = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                         return $(this).attr('Guid') + ',' +  $(this).attr('userNames');
                    }).get();
var result = items.join(';');
```

Comment: another way is simple awesome. it takes minimum efforts..... I used it and avoid two arrays.....thanks

Comment: The second way is how I would do it too. The first way was just to demonstrate that you didnt need to iterate twice if you wanted an array with both properties.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function getFormatedString(ar1,ar2){
var str="";
for(var i=0;i<ar1.length;i++){
str=str+ar1[i]+","+ar2[i]+";";
}

return str.substring(0, str.length - 1);;
}



    selectedGuids = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                         return $(this).attr('Guid');
                    })
                    .get();
    selectedUserNames = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                         return $(this).attr('userNames'); 
                    })
                    .get();
 console.log( getFormatedString(selectedGuids,selectedUserNames));
```

Comment: did you mean `merge` or are you trying to turn the 2 strings into a simpsons character?

Comment: your right.merge is not correct name for that function .i will change the name of function #thanks

Comment: `merge` is a totally appropriate name for the method, but "marge" is a simpsons character :)

Answer (score 1):

This code may help.

```
selectedDataArray = $('.chkAllDates:checked').map(function () {
                         return $(this).attr('Guid') + ',' + $(this).attr('userNames');
                }).get();

selectedDataString = selectedDataArray.join(";");
```

Comment: I suggested it first :P

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is always better to follow some standard object model, [**JSON**](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) is good choice.

```js
var array1 = ["array1.value1","array1.value2" ]
var array2 = ["array2.value1","array2.value2" ]

var mergedArray = { array1 : array1, array2 : array2 };

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(mergedArray);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```